# Docker Compose: Detect whether image needs to be re-built

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a Docker setup (using docker-compose) to test one of my Python applications during development. It the docker-compose.yml starts up a Postgres Server, a Redis server and a PhantomJS server and then runs the tests using pytest.

This is what my `test.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
UP=$(docker-compose up -d redis postgres phantomjs 2>&1)
echo $UP
if [[ $UP == *"Starting radar_postgres"* ]]; then
    echo "Sleeping 10 seconds to wait for PostgreSQL server..."
    sleep 10
fi
docker-compose build tests && \
docker-compose run \
    --rm \
    -e GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID='$GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID' \
    -e GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET='$GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -e GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_TOKEN='$GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_TOKEN' \
    tests $@
```

First the dependencies are started. Due to the way `docker-compose up` works, they're automatically rebuilt when necessary.

Then I run a one-off job in my `tests` container. I use a one-off job instead of using `docker-compose up` because this way I can pass in arguments to the test framework.

The problem is that the container is always being rebuilt, even if the Dockerfile didn't change and no rebuild would be necessary. (Of course each step uses the cache, but it still takes 4-5 seconds.) On contrast, if I leave away the `docker-compose build` line, then the container is not being rebuilt when I change the Dockerfile.

Is there a way to rebuilt an image only if necessary?

Comment: Not related to the question, but if you use `-e GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID -e GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET` (no values), compose will copy the values from the environment for you.  You could also do that in your `docker-compose.yml` (key with no value).

Comment: @dnephin thanks a lot, that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that there is a discussion ([issue 1455](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1455)) to remove build from docker-compose.

> Compose's primary job is orchestration and not building, and that the Docker image is the natural place to draw that line

So it would be best to use `docker build` commands (which should only build images when necessary), instead of using `docker-compose build` (which might build a bit too aggressively)

Comment: Then I would have to replace all `build:` lines in the `docker-compose.yml` with an image, right?

Comment: @DaniloBargen yes, that is the idea.

Comment: even if you use `docker build` you'll see the same thing where it hits the cache.  I don't think there is any way around that.

Comment: omg.. thank you for this. `docker-compose build` was not working properly for me (I spent way too long debugging it)